# .htaccess rules in a sub directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've a folder named `test`, I can access it via `http://domain.com/test`. I'm trying to send every requests of `http://domain.com/test/XXX` (XXX = every thing) to a `php file`.

I used this in `test/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /control.php?path=$1  [L]
</IfModule>
```

`control.php` is in `test` folder too. But it doesn't work, i don't know in which rule i did a mistake! now every `http://domain.com/test/XXX` requests shows a `404 not found page`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ control.php?path=$1  [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What are `RewriteCond`s for?

Comment: To avoid applying Rewrite rule for a physical directory, file or link

Comment: You will at least need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` otherwise it will cause endless loop since same rule will execute for `control.php` as well.

Comment: If you want to remove all 3 RewriteCond then have Rewrite rule like this: `RewriteRule (?!^control\.php$)^(.*)$ control.php?path=$1 [L]`

Comment: how can we write condition as u said for avoiding .php files?

Comment: Just use: `RewriteRule (?!^.+?\.php$)^(.*)$ control.php?path=$1 [L]`

Comment: thanks ;) do u know any book or article on mastering htaccess? i'm really zero at it!

Comment: I think there is one book on mod_rewrite but I haven't read it. I have just gone through Apache mod_rewrite guide once and rest is all simple regex knowledge.